# Создать альяс для доменного имени

Tags: freebsd, dns

Проблема такая, есть доменное имя вида test.dev.ru через которое я могу обращаться к сайту. Так же зарегистрировано еще одно доменное имя вида site.ru. Как написать альяс чтобы при обращений к site.ru я видел данные с test.dev.ru. Всегда я это делал с помощью панели управления, а теперь в наличии лишь ssh доступ к freebsd серверу. Опишить процесс настроики этого дела или дайте линки на хорошие мануалы.

Comment: Зависит от того, какой установлен web-сервер. Вообще, это можно в настройках виртуалхостов сделать.

Comment: сделал альяс в настроиках виртуального хоста а что делать в настроках самого домена site.ru какие днс сервера прописать? И где я могу посмотреть адрес ns моего сервера??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас на сервере bind поднят? Посмотрите в процессах *ps ax | grep named*

Если да, то надо отредактировать named.conf Обычно он находится в /etc/namedb или /var/named/etc/namedb

Описываете новую зовну site.ru в файле named.conf, создаёте мастер-файл с описанием зоны. Затем рестартуете DNS сервер. Если не ошибаюсь, можно послать сигнал HUP демону named, чтобы он перечитал конфиги.

Также регистраторы требуют указывать вторичный сервер имён, а некоторые регистраторы требуют чтобы вторичный DNS не был в одной подсети с главным. В качестве вторичного DNS сервер можно воспользоваться бесплатным сервисом DNS.

Кстати, если у Вас нет администраторских прав на Вашем сервере, то Вы не сможете настроить DNS. В этом случае придётся иcкать бесплатный DNS сервис или регистрировать дополнительную услугу у провайдера.